# HTML page authentication using identity ADFS URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins, adfs

I have simple html page which display some customer reports on page using some javascript function. Javascript has ajax call to get customer reports from backend Spring REST API. In Spring REST API I have written "/api/saml" endpoint for authentication against ADFS using saml and jwt.

Below is the endpoint under which I have configured claims in ADFS:

```
https://idtest.companyName/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx?logintoRP=https://myappHOST/api/saml
```

I want to authenticate customer report page html page before accessing it. Page should be accessible to only those user who are authorized in ADFS and also I want implement SSO login for same.
How can I achieve SSO in my javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a SAML [client-side library](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Node would seem to be your best bet for Javascript.